# C#. WPF. Медленная работа приложения на Windows server 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, сервер

Есть приложение написано на С# (WPF), обрабатывающие данные с MSSQL 2012.
Приложение отлично работает на локальной машине, но когда переносим его на Windows Server 2012, начинаются тормоза, и начинаются они как раз при отображении данных датагрида.
Настройки SQL одинаковые, скорость выполнения запросов не превышают 1 сек.
Прошу помощи, почему у меня скорость отображения на локальной и серверной машинах разные.
Подозреваю, что на сервере не хватает какого-то компонента. Но вот какого?

Comment: А как работаете с сервером? Удаленно через Remote Desktop Connection или прямо за клавой и моником сервера?

Comment: Пользователь к серверу подключается через RDP

Comment: Если тормоза при прокрутке, то нужно в xaml у `DataGrid` задать `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`

Comment: Дело в самой отрисовке данных, DataGrid прорисовывается 25 сек. (650 строк), хотя скрипт SQL отрабатывает запрос за 0,1сек